How do I sum the max of each categories without helper column
I have several categories of objects (A13:A100) containing a price (column D13:D100). I would like a formula to sum the maximums price of each of the categories of object.
I thought it would be easy. But, what I did doesn't work. Here what I have.



rows
A Categories
B Other column
C Other column
D Prices





string


number


13
Fruits


1


14
Fruits


1


15
Meats


5


16
Fruits


3


17
Cereals


2


18
Cereals


3


19
Cereals


3



In that situation, I want to sum the max of the fruits, the max of the meats and the max of the cereals. So it would be 3 + 5 + 3 = 11.
I already tried three times.
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(FILTER(D13:D100, A13:A100 = UNIQUE(A13:A100)))))

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(D13:D100), {D13:D100, A13:A100}, 2, FALSE), 0)))

=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(MAXIFS(D13:D100, A13:A100, UNIQUE(A13:A100))))

But the answer is never 11. There will be new rows and categories over time, that's why in my formula I plan to the 100th row. I already know that I could just do it by step by adding a new column to help, but I want to avoid that.

So, while you are editing, I tried:
SUM(MAXIFS(E3:E9,B3:B9,{"Cereals","Meats","Fruits"}))

Edit: and you could add some data validation as well:


Thank you. It helps me to know the problem is not with SUM or MAXIFS. It's on the array.
Since the categories will change over time with the rows that are after. For example, I could have a new row which will be ice cream. To be able to incorporate any new lines and categories, I used UNIQUE or FILTER and ARRAYFORMULA.

@ManuelPelletier yes, I like using unique() to build lists so they update when doing things like this, then I tend to add an if() so errors due to blank info stay hidden. Will you be accepting any of the answers or upvoting since they obviously helped you?

You can also use QUERY to perform a SQL-like query that selects the maximum price D for each category A, excluding any rows where A is blank:
=SUM(QUERY(A13:D100, "SELECT MAX(D) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A"))




You may try:
=sum(choosecols(sortn(sort(A13:D,4,),9^9,2,1,),4))


